# How to show constantly (for 1-2 minutes) typing aciton in Telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I use telethon library.
I can show typing event one (for 5 seconds) but can't continue doing it.

Because I am using OpenAI that is not super fast I need to show typing event for longer (I can do it with delays).

```
async with client.action(event.chat_id, 'typing'):
    slow function here
```

How to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your "slow function" can be [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep):

```py
async with client.action(event.chat_id, 'typing'):
    await asyncio.sleep(60)  # 1 minute
```

…but the idea of having the context manager is for you to put your long-running operation inside:

```py
async with client.action(event.chat_id, 'typing'):
    result = await function_that_takes_long()

await client.send_message(chat, result)
```

which would be far more accurate than "a minute or two".

Make sure that `function_that_takes_long` does *not* block the thread, or the `asyncio` event loop won't be able to make any progress (and, by extension, Telethon won't be able to keep sending the action notification).

If your function is not really `async`, you should probably reach out for [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Comment: I did like you said, but it stops showing "typing" after sometime in function_that_takes_long

I believe the reason for that is that function_that_takes_long it self could send "debug" information (to another chat). Is that possible?

Comment: Make sure `function_that_takes_long` is *not* blocking the entire thread or the `asyncio` event loop will completely halt, and the library won't have a chance to do anything in the meantime. I will edit the answer to note that.

Answer (score 0):

To make typing status longer than 5 seconds, do something like this:

```py
async def keep_typing_while(chat_id, func):
    cancel = { 'cancel': False }

    async def keep_typing():
        while not cancel['cancel']:
            await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'typing')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    async def executor():
        await func()
        cancel['cancel'] = True

    await asyncio.gather(
        keep_typing(),
        executor(),
    )
```

And execute it like this:

```py
answer = {}

async def openai_caller():
    local_answer = await get_openai_completion(user_context.get_messages())
    answer['role'] = local_answer['role']
    answer['content'] = local_answer['content']

await keep_typing_while(message.chat.id, openai_caller)
```